# Close tooltip on click of close button

Tags: php, google-visualization

I am using google map geochart and i have added tooltip when user will click on any state then it will show the tooltip with state info. I need to add a close button in tooltip.when user will click on tooltip then tooltip will close.I have added this code to hide tooltip it close the tooltip but when hover on map then it shows it again.

```
<a class="clslink" href="javascript:;" id="test'.$valArr[1].'" onclick="closetip(this);" >Close</a>

function closetip(a)
{
    //alert($(a).attr('id'));
    var cls = $(a).attr('id');
    $("#"+cls).parent().parent().parent().hide();

}
```

Comment: I am trying to solve this using this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32387472/google-charts-visualization-dismiss-tooltip-on-click-away  but same proble.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37203653/5090771)?