# Google GeoCharts close tooltip on click

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am using Google GeoChart and I have added a tooltip. When a user clicks on any state, then it will show the tooltip with state info. I need to add a close button in tooltip. When a user will click on the tooltip, then tooltip will close. I have added this code in the Fiddle.

```js
function closetip(a) {
    //alert($(a).attr('id'));
    var cls = $(a).attr('id');
    $("#" + cls).parent().parent().parent().hide();
}
```

Comment: This is fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/SD4KA/321/

Comment: There is no function on the link href="javascription:;", unless you have a listener added its not going to trigger closetip()

Comment: please check the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/SD4KA/336/  it hide it once but shows again.

Comment: does anyone know how we can do this?

Comment: It is working with this. $(document).on('click', '.clslink', function(e)
 {
  
  geochart.setSelection(null);
    
 });

Comment: hey,I know this is old but I'm trying to do the same thing,Can you post the full code or jsfiddle of working version...? I really need it,thanks.