# working version code of close tooltips button on geochart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

Before anyone is going to Downvote my question for duplicate, I want you to know that I found the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37203653/google-geocharts-close-tooltip-on-click) but I'm still confusing how it works and I'm just a beginner on coding.

I would like to ask anyone for full working version code or jsfiddle example of how to close tooltips on geochart.

I tried

`document.getElementByClassName("google-visualization-tooltip").style.visibility=hidden;`

but it doesn't work, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, use the following tooltip options...

```
tooltip: {
  isHtml: true,         // <-- use html tooltips (vs. svg)
  trigger: 'selection'  // <-- lock tooltip in place when clicked
}
```

using `isHtml: true` will make the class `google-visualization-tooltip` available

however, it is not available until after a region is selected,

which is why we must set event listeners at the `document` level...

```
// click anywhere on tooltip to close
$(document).on('click', '.google-visualization-tooltip', function(e) {
  chart.setSelection(null);
});
```

---

see following working snippet (click anywhere on the tooltip to close)...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawRegionsMap,
  packages:['geochart']
});

function drawRegionsMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Country', 'Companies', 'Installations'],
      ['South Africa', 200, 3],
      ['Angola', 300, 4],
      ['Malawi', 400, 12],
      ['United States', 500, 19]
  ]);

  var options = {
    colorAxis: {colors: ['#00853f', 'black', '#e31b23']},
    backgroundColor: '#81d4fa',
    datalessRegionColor: '#f8bbd0',
    defaultColor: '#f5f5f5',
    displayMode: 'regions',
    resolution: 'countries',
    tooltip: {
      isHtml: true,
      trigger: 'selection'
    }
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('geochart-colors');
  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(container);
  chart.draw(data, options);

  // click anywhere on tooltip to close
  $(document).on('click', '.google-visualization-tooltip', function(e) {
    chart.setSelection(null);
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="geochart-colors"></div>
```

Comment: I'm really appreciated your help,you are the best!